# How to make a daily bithday report at morning?

Tags: civireport

Every day a person receives a list of who has a birthday on that day. But this happend at evening, when it useless, How to make it at morning?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you have a cron job scheduled to do this. See https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/scheduled-jobs/#timing for how to adjust your timing.

Comment: Thank you! i will try it

Comment: I found my report in Scheduled Jobs,its a Mail Reports (Daily) API Entity: Job
API Action: mail_report.  several month ago, It sent a report at 5 am, and every few days it sends 30 minutes late. now its 10 pm. How can i fix it? Im realy bad in this :(

Comment: Some cron systems can be configured to have random drift, although usually it's not cumulative. You'll have to look at how cron works on your system. It might be in a control panel if you have one (cron is outside of civi).

Comment: Thank you! i add Scheduled Run Date, and its updated cron maybe, at friday it was 8:30, at monday already 9:00.